# Java networking using threads, when one client leaves the other cannot communicate to the server

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create a server in java which accepts clients. Currently, two clients can connect to the server. However, when one leaves the other client can no longer communicate with the server. I think the issue is that my clientSocket is created outside my thread, which means it must be declared as 'final' because I use an innerclass. However, if I move it into the thread it cannot create the clientSocket. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I close the clientSocket when the client leaves it says "Broken Pipe" error because the clientSocket is final so it cannot be changed - ie the clientSocket is the same for both clients.

```
private BufferedWriter writer;  
private LODGame game; 
public Server(int port) throws Exception {
    try{
        // Listen on the given port.
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    game = new LODGame();
    }
    catch(BindException e){
        throw new Exception("Failed to create a server socket: "+
                    e.getMessage());
    }
}
public Server(int port, String map) throws Exception {
    try{
        // Listen on the given port.
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    game = new LODGame(map);
    }
    catch(BindException e){
        throw new Exception("Failed to create a server socket: "+
                    e.getMessage());
    }
}


public void run() throws Exception {

    final ServerSocket serverSocket = getServerSocket();

while (true){
    System.out.println("Listening for a client on port: "+
               serverSocket.getLocalPort());
    // Wait for a client to make contact.
    final Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
    // Contact ...
    System.out.println("A client has arrived.");

    Thread serverThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
        boolean quit = false;
        while (!quit){
            try{
            // Wrap the input stream in a BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                   new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            // Wrap the output stream in a BufferedWriter.
            writer = new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
            game.setWriter(writer);
            game.startNewGame();

            // Read lines until the client terminates.
            String request = reader.readLine();
            while(request != null){
                // Write the length of the line as a String.
                playerCommand(request);
                request = reader.readLine();
            }
            }
            catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IOException talking to the client: "+
                       e.getMessage());

            }
            finally{
            if(clientSocket != null){
                System.out.println("The client has gone.");
                break;
                // Close the socket to the client.
                //try
                //  {
                //      clientSocket.close();
                //  }
                //catch(Exception e)
                //  {
                //      System.out.println("Error" + e.getMessage());
        //                  System.exit(1);
                //                  }
            }
            }
           try
                {
                serverSocket.close();
                }
             catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error" + e.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
                }

        }
        }           
    };
    serverThread.start();   
}
}


protected ServerSocket getServerSocket(){
return serverSocket;
}

// The socket on which the listening is done.
private final ServerSocket serverSocket;
```

Answer (score 3):

No this has nothing to do with the `clientSocket` being `final`.  Your problem is that you are closing the `serverSocket` in the client thread.  You should be closing the clientSocket only at the end of the thread:

```
while (!quit) {
    try {
       ...
    } catch(IOException e){
       System.out.println("IOException talking to the client: "+
               e.getMessage());
    } finally {
       ...
       clientSocket.close();
    }
    // DON'T DO THIS: serverSocket.close();
}
```

The `serverSocket` should only be closed if `accept()` throws an `Exception` -- it should *not* be touched by the client thread at all.

Comment: I used to do this but I got a brokenpipe error when a client left.

Comment: @user506912 - of course you did, because the pipe got broken by the client disconnect.  Use mjames patent exception handling - catch, check, ignore.

Comment: Where in the code as it throwing a brokenpipe error @user506912?

Comment: @Gray It says Socket is closed at the bit where (it's commented out at the moment) "IOException talking to the client" now, instead of broken pipe.

Comment: Then Martin is right @user506912.  If the client closes its side of the connection you'll get that.  It can be caught and safely ignored.

Comment: @Gray But I think the problem is that both clients are on the same socket so the other can no longer communicate to the server.

Comment: That's impossible @user506912.  Each client gets it's own socket.  Each `accept` call returns a unique socket for each connection.  Each client handler thread is free to close its `clientSocket`.  I assure you this is true.  `System.out.println("clientSocket = " + clientSocket);` if you want to be sure.  It will be a different object.

Comment: @Gray It's done outside the thread though. And final means there can only be one clientSocket, so they must be on the same one, which is why the other client cannot communicate because the socket is now closed. That's why I think there's an issue. I'll check, though. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: @user506912 The `close` statement should be done _inside_ the thread, not out.  `final` _does_ mean that there is only one but only one EACH TIME through the loop.  The next call to accept will create a new `final` `clientSocket`.

Comment: @Gray okay, thanks. I will try to catch the closure and ignore it.

Comment: @user506912 - Gray is surely correct.  There is a different socket-pair for each client-server connection, and the socket returned from accept() represents the server endpoint per client.

Comment: It works if clients come and leave one after another, after I followed yours and @Gray 's advice. But if one leaves the other cannot continue because it says socket closed. I will ask in a separate question.

Comment: You must capture the clientSocket instance for each thread.  You have to pass it into the thread at creation time!

Comment: @user506912 Hrm.  The `writer` is defined at the top of the class.  It should be a local variable in the Thread itself.  That might be the issue.

Comment: @Gray I'm afraid it has to be defined there, it's used in my constructors which in turn is used in another class.

Comment: @user506912 Also you don't need the `while (!quit){` loop at the top of your client.  It will only go through that loop once.

Comment: @user506912 Each client has it's own `clientSocket` with it's own input and output streams.  If you are setting a common `writer` class then when one client quits all of the other clients will throw an exception trying to WRITE to the stream that was just closed.

Comment: @Gray aha! So I need to create a new writer for each client in the thread! :D

Comment: @user506912 Yes, you _must_ do this.  Each client has it's own input and output streams.  They are unique to the `clientSocket`.

Comment: @Gray - nice catch re. the writer instance. It's the first line in the code!

Comment: Thanks @Martin.  And thanks for the help.  I finally took his code and imported it into my Eclipse.  It's hard to look at poorly formated code with multiple bugs outside of the editor.